# CSS navbar background showing up as white instead of transparent

Tags: css

My navbar background keeps showing up as white instead of transparent no matter what I do.

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 16px;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

:before,:after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

header,
section,
footer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.justify-content-between{
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.align-items-center{
    align-items: center;
}

.header .logo{
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 125px;
    height: auto;
}

.header .nav{
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header .nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header .nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.header .nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    font: 18px sans-serif;
    color: #5D5D5D;
}

.home-section{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: gray;
}

.home-section .row{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.home-section .slide{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.home-section .slide:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Neil O'Mara | Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="home-section">
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('bimg1.jpg');">
            <div class="row">

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well so we can have a better understanding of your issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined any styles related to background or opacity on the header

Try:

```
header {
    background: red;
    opacity: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your expected result? The [default browser background color is white](https://www.exratione.com/2011/07/set-the-body-element-background-color-property-even-if-its-white/#:%7E:text=The%20default%20background%20color%20for,set%20by%20the%20browser%20configuration.). It looks like the header section is not overlapping with the content of the page, and that's why it's still white.

You could add the following code to set a custom background color for the header

```
header {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```